# Remove css classes on Ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First of all im new to Jquery Ajax . i Have Loaded some content into DIV using ajax load method and so far all coding went good until now . i have a little share button that will add a class to 3 buttons and itself once its been clicked . i have used a script to accomplish this function but that script wont Work with Ajax . i have spent hours googling to find a solution but none of the proposed solutions worked for me .so here i am. Below is a piece of content that will load through the ajax into div

```
<div id="2">
        Track Name :- <b>Wiggle</b>
        <br>By :- <a target="_blank" href="../members/profile.php?id=1">USER NAME</a>
        <br>
        <button class="playback btn btn-primary btn-sm hdnbtn"><i class="fa fa-play"></i> Play</button>
        <audio src="../members/memberfiles/1/Wiggle.mp3">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
        </audio>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success hdnbtn" href="downloader.php?fld=1&amp;name=Wiggle.mp3" name="dwn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download MP3</a>

            <button class="btn btn-primary sharebtn"> Share</button>

            <div class="shareoptions hide">
                <a target="_blank" href="#" class="hide btn btn-sm btn-social btn-facebook socialhdn"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>  Share on Facebook</a>
                <a target="_blank" href="#" class="hide btn btn-sm btn-social btn-twitter socialhdn"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>  Tweet this </a>
                <a target="_blank" href="#" class="hide btn btn-sm btn-social btn-google-plus socialhdn"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>  Share on goole</a>
            </div>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:void();" class="cls_close hide btn-primary btn btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-minus"> Show Less</i></a>
        <input type="hidden" value="Wiggle.mp3" name="file_name">
        <input type="hidden" value="#" name="link">
    </div>
```

i have tried using on() method and live() method even though live is depreciated . But i cannot get it working properly . When i click the button i get the Javascript message , but it does not remove the 'hide' class at all

```
$(document).on('click' , '.sharebtn' , function(){
        $(this).closest('audio').find('.shareoptions').removeClass('hide');
        alert('Test');
    });
```

if you can suggest me a solution and point out where what went wrong i will really appreciate it , alot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest` traverse parent elements. Since `audio` is not a parent of `.sharebtn`, `$(this).closest('audio')` will return nothing.

But `.shareoptions` is a sibling of `.sharebtn`, so just use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings) or [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

```
$(this).next('.shareoptions').removeClass('hide');
```

Comment: Nicely Explained . Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: and also i need to add a class for the play button and download button as well . how do i do that here ?

Comment: figured it out .. :-)

Comment: @SithiraMunasinghe Good ahah, was about to answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have used `closest('audio')` which finds element in parent hierarchy and not sibilings. In your case audio is sibling of `.sharebtn`.

You have to find `shareoptions` at same level of button, see  below code

```
$(document).on('click' , '.sharebtn' , function(){
    $(this).next('.shareoptions').removeClass('hide');
    alert('Test');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the other 2 answers, you can also use the following solution:

```
$(this).parent().find('.shareoptions').removeClass('hide');
```

Comment: @SithiraMunasinghe There's no need to comment on each answer to thank them. The upvote button is there for that ;)